# Mysql Date and Time Difference

Tags: mysql, datetime

I have a table which has one field start_time with follwing records:

```
2011-07-26 14:30:00
    2011-07-28 08:00:00
```

What I need to do is compare the field *`start_time`* with the current date-time and show records only if the difference between them is less than 5 minutes.  It should show records of current date only

This is what I tried:

```
SELECT * FROM jqcalendar WHERE StartTime <= NOW() - INTERVAL 5 MINUTE
```

Comment: You may need to clarify your question instead of repeating the same comment over again. At least your query is not showing any attempt to show "records of current date only", also you should make sure your example data contains "today's" data (2011-07-28 was yesterday where I live).

Comment: @rajesh: What do you mean with "if current (system) datetime is less than 5 min"? In comparison to `StartDate` value? So `StartDate` is in the future?

Answer (score 2):

Use `DATE_ADD/DATE_SUB` for date-calculations:
 http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add

so `StartTime <= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 5 MINUTE)` should do the trick

Answer (score 2):

use mysql function TIMEDIFF(date1, date2)

```
select * from jqcalendar WHERE  TIMEDIFF(now(), StartDate) < 500
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timediff

Comment: its not showing records of current date. I need only current date records

Comment: just switch the arguments in the function. it should be TIMEDIFF (now(),StartDate)

Comment: @MartinTaleski: What is `5` in your example? Is it minute, day, ...? MySQL reference is perhaps not clear about the conversion of `TIMEDIFF` result into number.

Comment: actually five is the seconds... however 5 minutes is not 300 but 500 (00:05:00). Five hours would be 50000 (5:00:00) and five and a half is 53000 (5:30:00).

Answer (score 1):

have you tried

```
StartTime > NOW() - INTERVAL 5 MINUTE
```

? I think you just turned around your operator.

Comment: its not showing records of current date. I need only current date records

Answer (score 0):

`TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,start_time,now()) < 5`

Comment: time difference between now and start_time if less then 5 minute then yes.

Comment: @raulsi Consider amending the answer to incorporate the comment